# JOLT Specification to Transform JSON field value to field name

Tags: json, mapping, transformation, jolt

I am trying to convert the below JSON payload into a JSON which has the field name as the value of the field:
The jolt file that I have is working if field values are different. But if field values are the same then it is giving an array in the response.

Can you please help to provide jolt specifications for this?

Input JSON Payload :

```json
{
  "action": {
    "allowPartialSuccess": true,
    "records": [
      {
        "ZuoraSubscriptionExtId": "962041ad-e673-492a-a071-5e0ab74ea001",
        "CPQSubscriptionID__c": "5640029343"
      },
      {
        "ZuoraSubscriptionExtId": "962041ad-e673-492a-a071-5e0ab74ea001",
        "CPQSubscriptionID__c": "5640029343"
      }
    ],
    "type": "update"
  }
}
```

`

Expected output JSON Payload :

```json
{
  "action" : {
    "allowPartialSuccess" : true,
    "records" :  {
      "962041ad-e673-492a-a071-5e0ab74ea001" : {
        "CPQSubscriptionID__c" : "5640029343"
      }
    }, {
      "962041ad-e673-492a-a071-5e0ab74ea001" : {
        "CPQSubscriptionID__c" : "5640029343"
      }
    } ,
    "type" : "update"
  }
}
```

JOLT specification that I am using :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "action": {
        "allowPartialSuccess": "action.allowPartialSuccess",
        "records": {
          "*": {
            "CPQSubscriptionID__c": "action.records.@(1,ZuoraSubscriptionExtId).CPQSubscriptionID__c"
          }
        },
        "type": "action.type"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Your expected output is wrong. you cant have 2 same object in your record **that is not array**

Answer (score 2):

You can use this **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1.&", // &1 replicates the literal "action"
        "records": {
          "*": {
            "C*": "&3.&2.@(1,ZuoraSubscriptionExtId).&" // &3 replicates the literal "action" (by going three level up the tree), &2 for "records", & replicates the current level attribute
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: But, This answer has the same result!

Comment: No, not the same, but I think that you wanted to notify for the extra object wrapper comes after "records", but that would make it an array rather than an object, eg. the desired output should presumably be two consecutive objects with different labels. Otherwise that is already a wrong JSON value. @MohammadReza

Comment: If assume desired output is an object we have the same ids for that. so to prevent the same values that create an array in output, we need a `cardinality` spec.

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output is wrong in the question.

If you want an **object** in your record, You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "&": "&1.&",
        "records": {
          "*": {
            "CPQSubscriptionID__c": "&3.&2.@(1,ZuoraSubscriptionExtId).CPQSubscriptionID__c"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "records": {
          "*": {
            "*": "ONE"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And if you want an **array** in your output. You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "records": {
          "*": {
            "CPQSubscriptionID__c": "&3.&2[].@(1,ZuoraSubscriptionExtId).CPQSubscriptionID__c"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```